# How to swap placement of two elements, including their classes/ids with onclick?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, swap

I'm trying to switch the positions of two divs with an onclick event.

The divs have the same basic format (width, height), but an additional class and id change the way they look.

So, I have two functions that successfully change the id and class names, but there is no visual change.

Here they are:

```
function whenClickedFilled(){
    console.log("filled");
    this.firstElementChild.id = "empty";
    this.firstElementChild.className = "puzzlepiece emptyDivClass";

}

function whenClickedEmpty(){
    console.log("empty");
    this.firstElementChild.id = "filled";
    this.firstElementChild.className = "puzzlepiece";

}
```

I'd like to know what the best way is to alternate between classes/ids onclick.

Here is my [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r84BZ/).

Comment: So what's supposed to happen? You know there are no styles for `emptyDivClass`, which is the class applied on a click, adding styles makes a difference -> **http://jsfiddle.net/r84BZ/1/** ?

Comment: I see in your full code that you are assigning the id "filled" and "empty" to multiple elements. This is bad practice. Id attributes should always be unique. You should use a class instead.

Comment: Could we add suggestions to make it work that are beyond the scope of the question?

Comment: "CSE 190M Homework 4 (Fifteen Puzzle) style sheet" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're really looking to do is not swaping the class and id, but swap the elements themselves.  This will make sure the numbers contained within the div's is also transfer with the swap.

You still need to implement the logic checks to see if the element should be able to swap with the empty block and there looks like theres a bug when you click empty space itself.   But, this should get you on the right track.  I recommend placing a debugger statement to step through the code with dev tools open. It will help understand whats taking place.  Good luck.

```
 function whenClickedFilled(){
        console.log("filled");
        //Get the div element and parent
        //Then determine the parent of the empty div

        var clickedDiv = this.firstChild; //this refers to the TD clicked, get the child div element
        var clickedDivParent = this; //this is TD
        var emptyDivParent = emptyDiv.parentElement; //stored the empty div reference into a global, retrieve the parent as this could change

        //Remove the empty and clicked div's from their container
        emptyDivParent.removeChild(emptyDiv) 
        clickedDivParent.removeChild(clickedDiv);

        //Add the elements back to the containers but swapped
        clickedDivParent.appendChild(emptyDiv);
        emptyDivParent.appendChild(clickedDiv);   
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tWrD2/

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! @cgatian : yes I'd love suggestions. I'm working on the assignment by myself for practice, but with few humans to ask for help in person, I've found the internet to be only so helpful.

Comment: I wasnt aware of the replaceChild method @RobG used below. Use that in place of remove/append

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to switch the positions of two divs with an onclick event

If you want to swap two adjacent nodes, you can do something as simple as:

```
function swapAdjacent(el0, el1) {
  el0.parentNode.insertBefore(el1, el0);
}
```

If you want to swap any two elements in the DOM, you can do something like:

```
// Swap the postion in the DOM of el0 and el1
function swapElements(el0, el1) {

  // Create a temp node that can replace el0
  var tmp = el0.cloneNode(false);

  // Replace el0 with tmp
  el0.parentNode.replaceChild(tmp, el0);

  // Replace el1 with el0
  el1.parentNode.replaceChild(el0, el1);

  // Replace temp node with el1
  tmp.parentNode.replaceChild(el1, tmp);
}
```

and some test markup:

```
<div id="d0">div 0</div>
<div id="d1">div 1</div>
<button onclick="
  swapElements(document.getElementById('d0'), document.getElementById('d1'));
">Swap d0, d1</button>
<button onclick="
  swapAdjacent(document.getElementById('d0'), document.getElementById('d1'));
">Swap adjacent</button>
```

Of course the two elements to swap must be consistent with the surrounding elements, e.g. you can't swap an option element with a div and expect everything to work, but you can probably swap a span with a div.

If you want to swap elements by clicking on one or the other:

```
<div id="d0" onclick="swapElements(this, document.getElementById('d1'))">div 0</div>
<div id="d1" onclick="swapElements(this, document.getElementById('d0'))">div 1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution provided by [fuell](http://biostall.com/swap-and-re-order-divs-smoothly-using-jquery-swapsie-plugin) when I was searching fo an actual html swap:

```
<div id="div_1">THIS IS DIV 1</div>  
<div id="div_2">THIS IS DIV 2</div>  
<a href="javascript://" class="go-swap">Go Swap!</a> 

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".go-swap").click(function() {  
        $("#div_1").removeAttr("style");
        $("#div_2").removeAttr("style");
        var tmp = $("#div_1").html();
        $("#div_1").empty().append($("#div_2").html());
        $("#div_2").empty().append(tmp);
    });  
});
```